# Error to open WSO2 Integration Studio 8.1.0 in a Macbook Pro with macOS Monterey 12.6

Tags: macos, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

When trying to run WSO2 Integration Studio 8.1.0 in my Macbook Pro with macOS Monterey 12.6 (21G115), I get the error "The application 'IntegrationStudio.app' cannot be opened". This after having already allowed the use in System Preferences.

In addition to the above message, the error report below is displayed:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 2EFBA358-2424-419A-9BEB-79BCA583FA85
CrashReporter Key:   BC7F03EA-9B04-CF98-39FA-A3CA30ADDB07
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro15,1
Process:             IntegrationStudio [53198]
Path:                /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/IntegrationStudio
Identifier:          WSO2-Integration-Studio
Version:             8.1.0 (8.1.0.202203281342)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           WSO2-Integration-Studio [13620]

Date/Time:           2022-10-12 15:50:44.7626 +0100
Launch Time:         2022-10-12 15:50:44.7117 +0100
OS Version:          macOS 12.6 (21G115)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1 

Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

No thread state (register information) available

Binary Images:
Binary images description not available

Error Formulating Crash Report:
_dyld_process_info_create failed with 6
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
thread_get_state(PAGEIN) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
thread_get_state(EXCEPTION) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
thread_get_state(FLAVOR) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"IntegrationStudio","timestamp":"2022-10-12 15:50:46.00 +0100","app_version":"8.1.0","slice_uuid":"bf0baa93-fe7a-3039-ac22-e0007dc821f4","build_version":"8.1.0.202203281342","platform":0,"bundleID":"WSO2-Integration-Studio","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.6 (21G115)","incident_id":"2EFBA358-2424-419A-9BEB-79BCA583FA85","name":"IntegrationStudio"}
{
  "uptime" : 160000,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-10-12 15:50:44.7117 +0100",
  "procRole" : "Default",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 502,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro15,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 166412539089402,
  "coalitionID" : 13620,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.6",
    "build" : "21G115",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-10-12 15:50:44.7626 +0100",
  "incident" : "2EFBA358-2424-419A-9BEB-79BCA583FA85",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 53198,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 166412589247657,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "IntegrationStudio",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/IntegrationStudio.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/IntegrationStudio",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"8.1.0","CFBundleVersion":"8.1.0.202203281342","CFBundleIdentifier":"WSO2-Integration-Studio"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"00BD7B61-9ABE-567B-AF48-097D89C9E211","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "WSO2-Integration-Studio",
  "crashReporterKey" : "BC7F03EA-9B04-CF98-39FA-A3CA30ADDB07",
  "wakeTime" : 110846,
  "bridgeVersion" : {"build":"19P6067","train":"6.6"},
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "D8E532FC-8D1B-4DB3-AAFA-94A7D14A163A",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid)"},
  "termination" : {"namespace":"CODESIGNING","flags":66,"code":1},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadHighlighted" : 0
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "6112e14f37f5d11121dcd519",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "6332549e700e8d49302bbc77"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000223
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000486
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
},
  "reportNotes" : [
  "_dyld_process_info_create failed with 6",
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed",
  "Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\\_(ツ)_\/¯",
  "thread_get_state(PAGEIN) returned 0x10000003: (ipc\/send) invalid destination port",
  "thread_get_state(EXCEPTION) returned 0x10000003: (ipc\/send) invalid destination port",
  "thread_get_state(FLAVOR) returned 0x10000003: (ipc\/send) invalid destination port"
]
}

Model: MacBookPro15,1, BootROM 1731.140.2.0.0 (iBridge: 19.16.16067.0.0,0), 6 processors, 6-Core Intel Core i7, 2,6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 630, Intel UHD Graphics 630, Built-In
Graphics: Radeon Pro 560X, Radeon Pro 560X, PCIe, 4 GB
Display: LG ULTRAWIDE, 2560 x 1080 (UW-UXGA - Ultra Wide - Ultra Extended Graphics Array), Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, Micron, 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, Micron, 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Jul 12 2021 19:26:30 version 9.30.464.0.32.5.76 FWID 01-45ccefcd
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: BillBoard Device
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: 2K HD Camera
USB Device: USB Billboard Device
USB Device: Apple Watch Magnetic Charging Cable
USB Device: T2Bus
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 47.5
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 47.5
```

Has anyone had this problem? How did they solve it? I've already tried to reinstall, but after using it again, the same error is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue right after upgrading my Mac. What I did was reinstalled the Integration Studio and immediately updated the Integration Studio before continuing on the development.

Try updating the Integration Studio as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since IntegrationStudio isn't distributed via the official channel, it doesn't have a signature. Use this  `codesign --force --deep --sign -  IntegrationStudio.app` to manually sign it.